# PayPal processing, do i require to implement a notification listener?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

Im building a website for a costumer and integrating paypal payment to it, the costumer wants to verify all transactions manually, in this case is it necesary to implement a notification listener?

I am usign codeigniter for the project.

Thanks for the advice !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "customer wants to verify all payments manually"? Will your customer use Paypal panel or you will developed a screen for settle transactions? It really depend how your customer wants to design the application to work.

1. If your customer want to verify all transactions by login in to Paypal panel then it is not necessary to impelment IPN etc in the system.
2. But, if you are going to develop a web page where you display all the transactions and your customer will verify manually, then you must setup IPN.

Comment: Yes he will login to paypal to verify, thanks for the answer Nouman